# getting unexpected t string error

Tags: php, forms

i just wanted to pass data from html to another php file through php post but getting error as:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in D:\Hosting\10378233\html\shanfolder\fulltest\index.php on line 4
```

while the html code is :

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<div><label for="cardlink">Card Image Link:<input type="text" name="cardlink" id="cardlink" style="width: 602px; height: 25px" /></label></div><div><input type="submit" value="GO"/>
</div>
</form>
```

and php file index.php code is this :

```
<?php
$cardlink = $_POST['cardlink'];
<p>Card Image Link :</p>  <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($cardlink, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" />
?>
```

Comment: waiting for your replies...

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing the PHP and HTML syntax together which is wrong.

To add the HTML code you must end the PHP code with `?>` delimiters.

Or you can add HTML code into PHP code using echo statement.

Example for both.

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $cardlink = $_POST['cardlink'];

    echo '<p>Card Image Link :</p>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($cardlink, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); ?>" />';
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<?php
    $cardlink = $_POST['cardlink'];
?>
<p>Card Image Link :</p>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($cardlink, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just close **`<?php`** tag like this

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['cardlink'];
?>
<p>Card Image Link :</p>  <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($cardlink, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" />
?>($feed);
```

**Illustration:**

```
$firstname = $_POST['cardlink'];
    ?>
    ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, you didn't close you `<?php ?>` block

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['cardlink'];
?>
<p>Card Image Link :</p>  <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($cardlink, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who took time to check my question and answered the question to help me....

Answer (score 0):

You are opening php tags inside of opened php tags. Try this

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['cardlink'];
?>
<p>Card Image Link :</p>  <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($cardlink, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In the index.php you should print that HTML code, you shouldn't just put in there. Either print it, or just close the php code before the html code.